# Easy command to clear temp tables from memory

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, temp-tables

Often, when testing stored procedure code for improvement or change requests, I find myself copying and pasting blocks of the code directly into Management Stuido, tweaking the variables and running them.

However, a lot of the time the code is reliant on temp tables (not table variables) which are created during the stored procedure run. In normal course of operations those tables are disposed on when the sproc is finished executing, but when they're run directly in management studio, they obviously stick around in memory.

That means I can't just re-execute the code on each tweak, because it tries to re-create the tables and causes an error.

Sometimes it's easy enough to tweak the code to avoid this, but when there's a lot of tables that's a bit impractical. There's always copying and pasting the code into a new query window each time, but that gets annoying really quickly.

Is there any way to simply clear out temp tables from the memory in the current session, so you can just start afresh on each run?

Comment: drop table #temptable at the end of your script

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Thanks, but as I said it's a bit annoying if there's a lot of these tables kicking around. Was curious to know if there was one catch-all way of clearing them. Perhaps the answer is just "no, don't be so lazy" :)

Comment: You can do a reconnect from the menu or context menu `connection -> change connection`. You will however end up in the default database and not the one that you previously were in.

Comment: @MikaelEriksson Ah, that's definitely an improvement. A quick USE statement minimises the inconvenience. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: Why not just create a throw away proc? `CREATE PROC _P AS /*SomeCode*/; GO; EXEC _P; DROP PROC _P;` isn't much additional typing. You could create an SSMS template for it if too much!

Comment: @MartinSmith Because it's often easier to see the workings of a sproc by pulling it out into separate queries. Yes, you can make a copy and put in messages and select statements, but it's not always the easiest way to get what you want. As I said above though, could the answer is "no, don't be so lazy" :)

Comment: @MattThrower There isn't any difference. Just put your arbitrary statements in place of SomeCode above. You can then tweak it as desired and execute as many times as you want without having to manually reconnect...

Comment: @MartinSmith Oh, I see. Good point! Had assumed you were suggesting I copy the whole sproc, not paste what I needed into the middle, but that's just dumb of me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The comments cover the most frequent methods, which for completeness are:

1. Right click in query window and go to `Connection > Change Connection`, causing the session to refresh, hence dropping the temp tables
2. Copy SQL to a new window does the same

When testing, I frequently have block commented drop commands at the top of the testing window that you can select and run (Hit F5), like so:

```
/*    
DROP TABLE #TEMP1
DROP TABLE #TEMP2    
*/

SELECT TOP 1 * 
INTO #TEMP1
FROM Users

SELECT TOP 1 * 
INTO #TEMP2
FROM Users
```

So you just simply highlight the lines between the comments and run the selected statements.

Usually if I'm happy the entire query will run, I'll just have the `DROP` statements at the end, so I can re-run over and over, unless of course you want to interrogate the `#TEMP` tables.

Answer (score 2):

A small stored procedure to put in your project.

```sql
--
-- Drop all #temporary tables of active connexion.
--
CREATE PROCEDURE DropTempTables
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    declare @sql nvarchar(max)
    
    SELECT 
        @sql = concat(@sql, 'DROP TABLE ', SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, CHARINDEX('___', t.name)-1), '; ')
    FROM tempdb.sys.tables AS t
    WHERE t.name LIKE '#%[_][_][_]%'
    AND t.[object_id] = OBJECT_ID('tempdb..' + SUBSTRING(t.name, 1, CHARINDEX('___', t.name)-1))

    exec sp_executesql @sql
END
GO
```

Then you can use it like that.

```sql
exec DropTempTables

SELECT * 
INTO #myTempTable
FROM table

SELECT * 
INTO #myTempTable
FROM table
```